# How can I convert nested dictionary keys to strings?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

`original` dictionary keys are all integers. How can I convert all the integer keys to strings using a shorter approach?

```
original = {1:{},2:{101:"OneZeroOne",202:"TwoZeroTwo"}}

result = {}
for key in original:
    if not key in result:
        result[str(key)]={}
    for i, value in original[key].items():
        result[str(key)][str(i)] = value
print result
```

prints:

```
{'1': {}, '2': {'202': 'TwoZeroTwo', '101': 'OneZeroOne'}}
```

Comment: how many levels do you need to recurse?

Comment: ```...shorter approach...``` - execution time or less lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what types of data you have:

```
original = {1:{},2:{101:"OneZeroOne",202:"TwoZeroTwo"}}
result= json.loads(json.dumps(original))
print(result)
```

prints:

```
{'2': {'101': 'OneZeroOne', '202': 'TwoZeroTwo'}, '1': {}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def f(d):
    new = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = f(v)
        new[str(k)] = v
    return new
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import json
original = {1:{},2:{101:"OneZeroOne",202:"TwoZeroTwo"}}
text = json.dumps(original)
json.loads(text)
```

out:

```
{'1': {}, '2': {'101': 'OneZeroOne', '202': 'TwoZeroTwo'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the number of levels, then a recursive solution is probably best:

```
def convert_dict(d):
    return {str(k): convert_value(v) for k,v in d.items()}

def convert_list(lst):
    return [convert_value(item) for item in lst]

def convert_value(v):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        return convert_dict(v)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        return convert_list(v)
    # more elifs..
    else:
        return v
```

if you know that all values are either dicts or simple values, then you can remove all the elifs and the `convert_list` function